# How to storage IdentityServer token in local database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 for configuration authentication service for my web application.
I alredy setting up identityServer with in memoryStorage.
The problem that i was asking myself is if I got a token from identityServer and later IdentiyServer restarts when the token is expired identitySever is able to recognize the token and  renew it?

If the answer it's the second can you give me some ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement your own IRefreshTokenStore and add it to your DI container
e.g:

```
// Add to DI
services.AddSingleton<IRefreshTokenStore , CustomRefreshTokenStore >();

// Create a new class that implements the IRefreshTokenStore
public class CustomRefreshTokenStore : IRefreshTokenStore
    {
        public Task<RefreshToken> GetRefreshTokenAsync(string refreshTokenHandle)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task RemoveRefreshTokenAsync(string refreshTokenHandle)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task RemoveRefreshTokensAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<string> StoreRefreshTokenAsync(RefreshToken refreshToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task UpdateRefreshTokenAsync(string handle, RefreshToken refreshToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any example implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The **IIdentityServerBuilder** interface has an extension, called **AddOperationalStore**.

The setup and database migration is documented here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/7_entity_framework.html

You can use it as:

```
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

var isrvBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();

isrvBuilder.AddOperationalStore(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
});
```